# Spring Security, to allow only users who have both roles to access the page

Tags: spring, spring-security

First of all, I'm sorry I'm not good at English.

I created a class to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable()
    .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers("/aaa/**", "/bbb/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/ccc", "/ddd/**").hasRole("AAA")
            .antMatchers("/zzz/**").access("hasRole('AAA') and hasAnyRole('MASTER', 'ZZZ'")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and() 
// continue....
```

The situation I want is:

the user have both "AAA" and "MASTER" -> can access /zzz

the user have both "AAA" and "ZZZ" -> can access /zzz

Many sites I referenced say that I can apply roles with SpEL inside the "access" method.

However in the zzz line, the access method doesn't accept a String parameter.

Could you please tell me how to apply it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the *older* `authorizeRequests` instead of `authorizeHttpRequests` which does support that. Why it itsn't available with the same flexibility in the new API beats me. You would need to use an `AuthorityAuthorizationManager` to build the rules but not sure how to combine them into a larger ruleset.

Comment: @M.Deinum I changed authorizeHttpRequests to authorizeRequests and It works. Thanks!